# is there a way i can change the colour of many shapes in pygame with a function

Tags: python, function, input, graphics, pygame

I am trying to code a clown with hair that the user can change colour of based on user input. How would I change BLUE to a variable to allow the user to input a colour? I have only used functions with numbers.

```
def hair():
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (240, 200), 40, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (180, 230), 30, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (300, 230), 30, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (320, 270), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (160, 270), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (210, 230), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (270, 230), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (200, 200), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (280, 200), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (150, 250), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(gameWindow, BLUE, (330, 250), 20, 0)
```

Comment: If you want some user-input, you presumably are using some "frontend" to your code. Please share a little more where your code is implemented in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. One way is to display rectangles with different colors. When the user clicks the rectangles the color changes accordingly, something like this in your events loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Different buttons here
        if yellow_button.collidepoint(pos):
            color = YELLOW
        if blue_button.collidepoint(pos):
            color = BLUE
```

Then you just replace the 'BLUE' in your code with 'color'.